# WebService how to not wait until task is completed

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

I have a c# function inside a WebService to save the records being modified or added.

```
public bool UpdateEmployeeInfo(DataSet ds, int userId) {

    bool returnVal = true;
    Guid employeeUid = Guid.Empty;


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(InfoTacto.Framework.WebServices.Common.GetConnectionString());
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, "UpdateEmployeeInfo");

    try {
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Contains("employee") && ds.Tables["employee"].Rows.Count > 0) {
            DataRow mainRow = ds.Tables["employee"].Rows[0];
            employeeUid = new Guid(mainRow["employeeUid"].ToString());
        }

        // depending on the tables being modified, _sendMessage can be true or false
        _sendMessage = EmployeeUpdate.UpdateEmployeeMethods(ds, trans, userId);

        trans.Commit();

    } catch (Exception err) {

        trans.Rollback();

        returnVal = false;

    } finally {
        //if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
        conn.Close();
    }

    // send push message for real time sync

    if (_sendMessage) {
        // this service sometimes take between 1 to 5 seconds so I dont want to wait
        // until it has finished...
        Utility.MessageService sqs = new MessageService();
        sqs.SendMessage("employeeUid=" + employeeUid);
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

After all tables are updated successfully I check I the webservice needs to send a Message (to other system), this action sometimes takes milliseconds or up to 5 seconds but I don't want my Desktop application to freeze waiting for my webservice function to complete.

```
// this service sometimes take between 1 to 5 seconds so I dont want to wait
// until it has finished...
Utility.MessageService sqs = new MessageService();
sqs.SendMessage("employeeUid=" + employeeUid);
```

> Any clue on how can I leave the server to complete that `SendMessage` function so my `UpdateEmployeeInfo` wont wait for it to complete in order to return my `returnVal` value to my client application.

Thanks

Comment: Use Multithreading.. create another thread and perform your task and make your main thread free for other task

Comment: Any sample on how can I do that?

Comment: Aside - there's not much benefit of using `SqlTransaction` here, as there is an implicit transaction already in place, except that you're changing to `ReadUncommitted` - which is probably not a good idea unless you really want dirty reads.  Also, there's not a single `using` statement in sight, which means you will be leaking resources.  And also, you might be sending the message even when the transaction fails.

Comment: @MattJohnson so SqlTransaction is not working on my code? I don't see which transaction is already in place.

Comment: I didnt say it wasn't working.  Just that it probably isn't necessary.  Then again, it depends on what `UpdateEmployeeMethods` is doing.  Hard to tell from your sample.  If it's just executing a single `SqlCommand`, then it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Task t = Task.Run(()=>
{
    Utility.MessageService sqs = new MessageService();
    sqs.SendMessage("employeeUid=" + employeeUid);
});
```

Comment: Is there any different between using your code or Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{});

Comment: StartNew is Dangerous. See [here.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: It's also dangerous just to fire this task and forget about it.  unless you await the result somewhere, you could potentially kill the task before it completes.  See also http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-Library-Methods-Shouldn-t-Lie

Answer (score 1):

You should consider not sending the message to the other system directly, regardless of whether you do it on another thread or not.  Instead, decouple the systems using a queue.  Push the message onto the queue and exit, then have the other system read from the queue.

There are lots of queuing infrastructures to consider, including MSMQ, Azure Storage Queues, Azure Service Bus Queues, RabbitMQ, and lots more.

Comment: Exactly im using Amazon SQS but dont want to hang my main Method if Amazon response delays.

Comment: That's something not obvious in your question.  But anyway, I'm surprised that you would get such a long delay.  Are your queue and app hosted nearby?  If not, consider writing to a local queue first, then having a separate process that pushes up to the main queue.  (This technique is often used in "occasionally-connected" client applications.)

Comment: I guess a separate process would be great solution. Good approach

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the client for Utility.MessageService using the latest WCF svcutil (version 4.5.1), it will actually generate asynchronous versions of your method calls for you.  You could then call `sqs.SendMessageAsync()`, which won't wait around after the message is sent.

Here's an example Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmailService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SendEmail(EmailDTO email);
}
```

using the 4.5.1 version of svc util, here is an excerpt from the generated client. Notice that there is a `Async` version of `SendEmail()`, `SendEmailAsync()`:

```
public partial class EmailServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IEmailService>, IEmailService
{

    . . .<SNIP> . . .

    public void SendEmail(EmailDTO email)
    {
        base.Channel.SendEmail(email);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendEmailAsync(EmailDTO email)
    {
        return base.Channel.SendEmailAsync(email);
    }
}
```

For me, the latest version of svcutil was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\svcutil`.  This version generated the accompanying `Async` versions of my service methods.  Earlier version of `svcutil`, also on my machine, did not generate the `Async versions`.

Comment: SendMessage is not a WCF service, the UpdateEmployeeInfo does, so I think I have to createa task that is independant of the main task as Khurram Ali commented, but dont know how :)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed WCF, because of the WCF tag.

Comment: The UpdateEmployeeInfo Does, but the other SendMessage is just a simple class.